# Где создавать модули в новых версиях nginx?

Tags: nginx

Раньше в старых версиях модули у nginx были в папке `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/`

Я поставил относительно новую версию `nginx version: nginx/1.17.7`
И теперь папка `/etc/nginx/` выглядит так:

```
/etc/nginx/
├── conf.d
│   └── default.conf
├── fastcgi_params
├── koi-utf
├── koi-win
├── mime.types
├── modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
├── nginx.conf
├── scgi_params
├── sites-available
├── snippets
├── uwsgi_params
└── win-utf
```

Где теперь мне следует создавать модули? Например такие:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     25565;
        proxy_protocol on;
        proxy_pass 0.0.0.0:25570;
    }
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы это делать в отдельном файле, а не в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Мой `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, я его не менял посте установки, система у меня debian 9:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Это что за система? Видимо в conf.d, но вообще-то можно в nginx.conf посмореть

Comment: @AlexeyTen в conf.d только http сервера можно добавить, а мне нужен stream, в nginx.conf нет ничего, я обновил вопрос, добавил свой nginx.conf

Comment: Ну добавьте пару строчек в nginx.conf